# How show a new feature layer in map?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, fields-attributes, feature-layer, arcgis-web-appbuilder, map-drawing

I'm creating a new feature layer like that:

```
createNewFeature: function (layer, geometry, layerInfo) {
    var loJsonFS = {
      "displayFieldName": layer.displayFieldName,
      "fieldAliases": layer.fieldAliases,
      "geometryType": layer.geometryType,
      "spatialReference": layer.spatialReference,
      "fields": layer.fields,
      "features": [{
        "attributes": loAttributes,
        "geometry": loGeometry,

      }]
    };
    var loFS = new FeatureSet(loJsonFS);

    var featureCollection = {
      layerDefinition: {
        "geometryType": layer.geometryType,
        "fields": layer.fields
      },
      featureSet: loFS
    };

    var loFL = new FeatureLayer(featureCollection, {
      mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND
    });

    this.map.addLayer(loFL);
```

`}`

But it does'nt show in the map. The attributes that receive are empty, and the geometry is based in a draw that user can do in the map. 
What I need to show it in the map?

Answer (score 1):

One piece of [information](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html) that you need to include is a definition expression.

```
featureLayer.setDefinitionExpression("STATE_NAME = 'South Carolina'");
```

> Sets the definition expression for the FeatureLayer. Only the features that match the definition expression are displayed. A definition expression limits the features available for display and queries by applying constraints to the layer's attribute fields.
>
> Setting a definition expression is useful when the dataset is large and you don't want to bring everything to the client for analysis.
>
> This method is typically called before adding the layer to the map. If the method is called after the layer is added to the map the layer will refresh itself to reflect the new definition expression.
>
> This definition expression is combined with the layer's default definition expression which results in a further restriction of the layer.

Comment: I don't want show an existing feature. I need show the created feature.